# Inserting JSON object into MySQL table with Angular/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

So I have a JSON object I want to insert into a field in a MySQL table. When I do a "console.log(thatjson)", it prints the JSON object in the console with the text [Object], with all the information available when you click on the object. However, when I do a "alert(thatjson)" it prints "object Object" in the alert box, and when I check that table in phpMyAdmin, the field which is varchar(2000) only stored a string which says [object Object].

In my php, i have $property = json_decode($request->getBody()); to decode the angular passed json data, apparently that did not help. : (

Any ideas?

Edit:

Relevant Code:

```
$scope.update = function(thatjson){                
             $http.put('api/envisiondb/0', thatjson).success(function(data) {
                $scope.properties = data;
          });
        };
```

PHP Slim:

```
function editProperty($id) {
    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $property = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $sql = "UPDATE db SET username=:username..."
```

The JSON object is just a regular everyday JSON object

Comment: Please show relevant code ... particularly how you are creating the `$http` request

Comment: @charlietfl hi charlie, i have updated with the relevant code

Comment: JSON is not an object - the whole point of JSON is that it is a string containing a serialized representation of an object. The variable you are manipulating here is not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass your request data through the `JSON.stringify()` function.