# Add JSON data to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, angularjs, json, database, grails

I'm developing a Grails concert application where I am acquiring the actual events from bandsintown.com using AngularJS.

```
 $.getJSON("http://api.bandsintown.com/events/search.json?&api_version=2.0&app_id=FYP&location=Dublin,Ireland", function(result)
```

I am able to retrieve the events and I now want to turn each event into an object and add them to my database, so I can have a unique page for each event with their subsequent details and whatnot.

Is anyone able to provide me guidance on how to do such a thing?

Thank you!

Comment: Seems to be a **broad** question.

Comment: Seems like an duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041851/inserting-json-object-into-mysql-table-with-angular-php

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(result);` and insert this string in your database at respective column.While reading use `JSON.parse(jsonstring):`

Comment: @Mistalis I did recognise that as I wrote my query. After about an hours worth of research, I found there to be a lot of information. So I decided to strip my question to its most basic form and ask it as I did.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's helpful, when you write a question, if you show an example of data and the result you want. Please [edit] your question to do that. By the way, I guess the JSON object you retrieved contains a collection of multiple events, and you want to insert each event in its own row of a table. You'll need to write code to do that -- to  iterate over the events.  Or you can treat your JSON object as a text string and just slosh it into a column of a table. But good luck searching it in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something a while ago as a plugin which may help you get your head around what you need to do :

```
private String viewTicketField(String jiraserver, String jirauser,String jirapass, String url, String customField) {
    if (url.endsWith('undefined')) {
        return
    }

    String output=''

    try {
        HBuilder hBuilder=new HBuilder()
        RESTClient http = hBuilder.httpConn(jiraserver, jirauser, jirapass,httpConnTimeOut,httpSockTimeOut)
        http.request(Method.GET ) { req ->
            uri.path = url
            response.success = { resp, json ->
                log.info "Process URL Success! ${resp.status}  "
                def result=JSON.parse(json.toString())
                if (result.fields."customfield_${customField}") {
                    output=result.fields."customfield_${customField}"
                }
            }
            response.failure = { resp ->
                log.error "Process URL failed with status ${resp.status}"
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        log.error "Failed error: $e.statusCode"
    }
    return output
}
```

HBuilder class can be found in [src](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-jenkins-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/jenkins/HBuilder.groovy)

After you have connected and got back your JSON response you then parse each line

You create a new domain class

```
String url 
String datetime
String app_id
String ticket_url
```

... and so on this is an entire entry from above url so for each **key that you actually require**  put in domain class as strings then parse each iteration with above code

```
{"id":13926481,"url":"http://www.bandsintown.com/event/13926481?app_id=FYP","datetime":"2017-02-23T17:00:00","ticket_url":"http://www.bandsintown.com/event/13926481/buy_tickets?app_id=FYP\u0026came_from=233","artists":[{"name":"Rackhouse Pilfer","url":"http://www.bandsintown.com/RackhousePilfer","mbid":null}],"venue":{"id":3334537,"url":"http://www.bandsintown.com/venue/3334537","name":"Convention Centre","city":"Dublin","region":"07","country":"Ireland","latitude":53.3500292,"longitude":-6.2385286},"ticket_status":"unavailable","on_sale_datetime":null
```